# Many people one try vs one person many tries - is there a name for this?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, game-theory, dice

Assuming we have two situations:

- (A) 500 People throw a six-sided dice, the result of each throw is the
  points given to each person
- (B) One person throws a six-sided dice 500
  times, the points of that person is the average of the throws

The expected value in A over all throws is the same as for B (3.5), but those are in my opinion obviously very different situations for the statistical considerations of the single person.

**Is there a name to differentiate between those scenarios?**

For background:
I had a heated dispute over whether its better-as in aiming for higher points-for a single person to throw the dice once or 500 times (No choice in-between, though that would be interesting, too..)
I was of the opinion that the 500 throws as a single person are quantitatively beneficial, as you are guaranteed 3.5 points, while a single throw depends strongly on luck.
I guess there is a the topic of max-min and min-max. In any case, I did notice that I lack a formal description/understanding for this particular situation, would love some help on that front!

Edit:
I missed to say, the dice is of course just a placeholder for any point generator with a distribution, perhaps of unknown nature.

My problem is that I cannot express the two scenarios formally enough to disprove the sentence "It does not matter whether a person throws the dice once or 500 times to get points, because the expected value is the same, because see the 500 people example". (Similarly I can't disprove the opposite statement..)

Comment: I'm not sure I quite understand the essence of your question, but you might be interested in the law of large numbers, and the central limit theorem

Comment: For an individual, the variance of their score is much smaller in (B) than in (A) so their score is more likely to be closer to the expected value $3.5$ more often.  So if you want a score of $3$ or more then (B) is better, while if you want a score of $4$ or more then (A) is better

Comment: this can be related to spatial and temporal spaces, that is, many people could represent space (successes occurring at a given moment in many different places) and one people time (successes occurring at different times but in the same place). Then the relation between the two processes, in space and in time, in some situations are related through ergodic theorems

Comment: @Milten I think the essence is this: Someone said to me, because the expected value of those two situations are the same, it does not matter to the individual whether to throw the dice once or 500 times. I disagree, but fail to express the difference in a convincing manner. I also fail to prove myself wrong on my impression, that those two cases are very different.

Comment: By "aiming for higher points", for example if your goal is to have $6$ points and otherwise you lose, then choosing $A$ is more likely ($\frac16$) than $B$ ($\frac1{6^{500}}$). More generally, if there is a non-symmetric payout function around $3.5$ that maps points to "gain/lose", then there might be a difference.

Comment: See also [risk aversion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Risk_aversion), that describes different preference between choices with same average payoff but different risk. Maybe the other person is risk neutral, and you are different.

Answer (score 1):

To make things simpler, consider instead a coin toss, with $0$ points for heads and $1$ point for tails. Suppose that you have an increasing utility function $u$ over points.

Then if you toss the coin once, your expected utility is

$$U_1=\frac{1}{2}u(0)+\frac{1}{2}u(1).$$

If you toss the coin twice and are awarded the average points over the two coin tosses, then your expected utility is

$$U_2=\frac{1}{4}u(0)+\frac{1}{2}u(1/2)+\frac{1}{4}u(1).$$

Your expected utility is higher from two coin tosses if

$$U_2-U_1=\frac{1}{2}u(1/2)-\frac{1}{4}[u(0)+u(1)]> 0$$

That is, if

$$u(1/2)>\frac{1}{2}[u(0)+u(1)]$$

This will hold if $u$ is strictly concave. In economics, a person with a strictly concave utility function is said to be risk averse. In this example the option of two coin tosses is less risky because the distribution of points second-order stochastically dominates the distribution of points from one coin toss.

[Note that the preference for one coin toss or two in this example boils down to whether someone prefers to get the expected value of $1/2$ for sure or to take the points from a single coin toss. Risk averse people always prefer a sure thing to a risky alternative with the same expected value, whereas risk neutral people are indifferent.]

Answer (score 0):

While I don't know that I can give you a *name* that is sufficient for this purpose, if you're willing to dive a bit deeper into probability theory, I can think of a mathematical concept which should work: the [standard deviation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_deviation) of the distribution.

The point is that the standard deviation of one die roll is rather high, whereas the standard deviation of the average of 500 die rolls is reallllly tiny, very close to zero.

The value of the standard deviation is a number $\ge 0$. To calculate it for $1$ roll of a fair die you take each possible outcome of that one die roll ($6$ values from $1$ to $6$), subtract $3.5$ and square the result, take the average, then take the square root, to get
$$\sqrt{\biggl((1-3.5)^2 + (2-3.5)^2 + (3-3.5)^2 + (4-3.5)^2 + (5-3.5)^2 + (6-3.5)^2\biggr) \biggm/ 6 \hphantom{bl}}
$$
(around 1.2 by my quick mental calculation, which is what I mean by "rather high" in this scenario).

To calculate the standard deviation of the outcome of the average of $500$ independent rolls of a fair die, one could follow the same principles although that is very tedious, but there are some [very nice rules](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_deviation#Rules_for_normally_distributed_data) for doing the calculation much more quickly. This is what one learns in probability theory, and I'll leave it at that, other than to repeat what I said before: for this particular example, the standard deviation for $500$ rolls is very close to zero.

In the two sides of the argument that you describe in your post, the value of the mean is the same in either scenario, namely 3.5. However, it would be a mistake to say that the two scenarios are statistically identical; the standard deviation is an important statistic that matters in applications. Just as an example, you can think of the standard deviation as a quantification of "risk" (in the answer of @smcc). So if one is risk averse then, given two probability distributions with the same mean, one will choose the one that has smaller standard deviation.

Comment: What a standard deviation of one roll mean?

Comment: Yeah, I was a bit careless, what I described is the standard deviation of the random variable itself. I'll fix that.

Comment: There is a sample statistic that is related to but subtly different from the standard deviation, namely the square root of the [sample variance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variance#Sample_variance). In the setting of this post this statistic applies to the actual outcomes of the die rolls (as opposed to the distribution of the outcomes). And as you say, it is indeed undefined for only 1 roll.